# Conditional Slutsky's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I've run into this problem that seems like it should be easy, but I cannot come up with a proof: Suppose $A_n$ is a sequence of random variables that is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable, and $A_n \stackrel{P}{\to}a$, where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant. Suppose $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$, and $B$ is a Borel set. Then

$$
P(A_nX \in B | \mathcal{F}_n) \stackrel{P}{\to} P(aX \in B)?
$$

This is sort of like a conditional version of Slutsky's Theorem. If needed we could assume that $B$ is a continuity set of $aX$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this is a special case of Lemma 4.1 in Lahiri (2003) Resampling Methods for Dependent Data. At the very least, it is very closely related and might point the way towards a method of proof.